# Undertanding the final_outputs of tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_docode

Tags: tensorflow, seq2seq

When I am reading the seq2seq tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq), I can't understand the output of function `tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_docode`.

The tutorial access the output the decoder used in training with `sample_id = outputs.sample_id`and `logits = self.output_layer(outputs.rnn_output)`while in the inference, `logits = outputs.rnn_output`and `sample_id = outputs.sample_id`. What does the `logits` and `sample_id` represent here? What is the content of the `final_outputs` of function [`tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_docode`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/dynamic_decode)?

Answer (score 6):

Okay, sorry for such a naive question. Figured it out from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/BasicDecoderOutput). So the `outputs` of `tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder` is an instance of [`class BasicDecoderOutput(rnn_output, sample_id)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/BasicDecoderOutput). I think the official document should have given this information.

And in more detail:

`rnn_output` is the output of the decoding cell.

`sample_id` is the id returned by a `Helper`. For `GreedyEmbeddingHelper`, the `sample_id` is [`argmax(outputs, axis=-1, output_type=dtypes.int32)`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/helper.py). And `sample_id` in the `outputs` of `tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder` should be of shape `[num_timesteps]` if `GreedyEmbeddingHelper`is used.